The Jackie Chan movie in which Jackie first fights then cooperates with a street gang
Please identify this Jackie Chan movie from these scenes:

A street gang chases Jackie with baseball bats in a parking lot.
There is a slutty girl with a lost soul. She has a little brother. She hooks in the gang.
Jackie goes into the gang's hideout alone to bring back a girl.
In the hideout, Jackie and the gang leader get on a table for a fight, they gaze each other for a while, then they suddenly start fighting with the gang leader's very fast fist which Jackie dodges amazingly.
The gang members also join in the fight.
Jackie beats a gang member with fridge doors.
Jackie wins this fight.
Later, other bad guys kidnap three of this gang members. They kill the biggest of them by putting him in a pulverizing machine and pouring his liquidized body in a sack. They send that sack to the gang leader with the remaining two gang members in order to threaten him. He becomes sick after looking in that sack.
After that, that gang and Jackie join forces.


Is it rumble in the bronx: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nc9pJKbjP_Q?

Actually from your description I'm sure it is Rumble in the Bronx which was filmed in Canada I believe (in fact it was Vancouver note that there are no black people despite supposedly portraying the Bronx): 


From imdb

Keong comes from Hong Kong to visit New York for his uncle's wedding.
  His uncle runs a market in the Bronx and Keong offers to help out
  while Uncle is on his honeymoon. During his stay in the Bronx, Keong
  befriends a neighbor kid and beats up some neighborhood thugs who
  cause problems at the market. Meanwhile, one of those petty thugs in
  the local gang stumbles into a criminal situation way over his head.
  Blinded by greed, his involvement draws his gang, the kid, Keong, and
  the whole neighborhood into a deadly crossfire. When the lazy cops
  fail to successfully resolve matters, Keong takes things into his own
  hands. Needless to say, much spectacular kung-fu and outrageous action
  sequences follow


Yes, it was! Thanks.
